Apply shader only to specific objects rendered within a sdl2 surface
I am using rust and sdl2 to make a game and I want to be able to apply shaders.
I am using the surface-based rendering of sdl2, then i send the pixel data to an opengl texture for the sole purpose of applying shaders.
Here is the problem: since I am drawing a texture as large as the background, changing the shader will still apply on the whole texture, and not the objects rendered with sdl2. Example:
'running: loop {
    for event in event_pump.poll_iter() {
        match event {
            Event::Quit { .. } => break 'running,
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    canvas.set_draw_color(Color::RED);
    canvas.fill_rect(Rect::new(10, 10, 50, 50)).unwrap();
    canvas.set_draw_color(Color::BLACK);

    unsafe {
        let surf = canvas.surface();
        let pixels = surf.without_lock().unwrap();

        gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        gl::TexImage2D(
            gl::TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            gl::RGBA as i32,
            800,
            600,
            0,
            gl::RGBA,
            gl::UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            pixels.as_ptr() as *const gl::types::GLvoid,
        );

        gl::UseProgram(shader_program);
        gl::BindVertexArray(vao);
        gl::DrawElements(gl::TRIANGLES, 6, gl::UNSIGNED_INT, ptr::null());

        // Set another shader program
        canvas.set_draw_color(Color::BLUE);
        canvas.fill_rect(Rect::new(100, 100, 50, 50)).unwrap();
        canvas.set_draw_color(Color::BLACK);
        // Rerender ?
        // Reset the shader program
    }

    window.gl_swap_window();
    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
}

How can i make it so that between calls of UseProgram and UseProgram(0), the shaders will be applied only on objects on the texture between these? (in this example the second blue square) I want to implement a similar thing as love2d shaders:
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setShader(shader)
    -- draw things
    love.graphics.setShader()
    -- draw more things
end

